# Linux crashes randomly

Tags: linux, debian, arch-linux, fedora, crash

In my Linux operating systems, I always have a problem, that my computer or desktop environment(not sure) is crashing randomly. For example, I'm opening settings, then my screen turns into a terminal with blinking cursor, and after 2 seconds I'm back into Lock screen where I need to login. However, even if I login again all my apps are closed.

I tried changing distributions and desktop environments. I tried Arch Gnome, Arch KDE, Fedora Gnome, Debian Gnome, but on all of them I have the same issue. But I didn't have it in the past, when I was using Manjaro 1 year ago(then I switched to Windows back).

I really would like to share some boot information with you, however I can't because the last system I tried was Debian, and on it, I couldn't even log back in, when I was logging after crash I had infinite loop(I logged password and lock screen appears back).

I checked my laptop on https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Laptop/Lenovo and it is compatible with Linux(Lenovo Legion Y7000P).

And one important thing. On windows I don't have this problem.

CPU: Intel Core i7 9750H @ 2.60GHz Motherboard: LENOVO LNVNB161216 (U3E1) RAM: 16,0GB Dual-Channel DDR4 @ 1330MHz Graphics: Generic PnP Monitor (1920x1080@144Hz) 2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti (Lenovo)

I have this problem on fresh install of all operating systems, in KDE I just installed the system, and tried to open Settings to change theme to dark one, but it crashed.

Does anyone had the same issue, please help me.

Comment: `NVIDIA` would be my guess at a culprit - have you checked *any* log files for potential error messages that may help you determine the cause of the desktop crashing?

Comment: No I haven't because after crash I can't log back into the computer

Comment: so ... you have a single crash and have to re-install linux? That's quite bad

Comment: To access some log files you can boot up a live disk or a rescue disk, mount the root file system, navigate to /var/log and read the files there which are in text such as messages, kernel.log, syslog, and Xorg.0.log. The most current Xorg.0.log may however be in ~/.local/share/xorg/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week, I came up with a solution, but still don't know what was wrong. I reinstalled arch linux without archinstall but manually instead, and also didn't add any extensions to the gnome. This made my system stable for 2 hours now(previously crashes were one time per +- 30 minutes) now.